# Probability message is sent correctly

Tags: probability

> A message of $10^k$ binary digits is sent along a fibre optic cable with high probabilities $p_0$ and $p_1$ that digits 0 and 1, respectively, are recieved correctly. If the probability of a digit in the original message being 1 is $a$, find the probability $Pr$ the entire message is received correctly.

I am stuck between two possibilities for this answer.

Approach 1: There are $a10^k$ 1's and $(1-a)10^k$ 0's. So
$$Pr=P(\text{All 1's send correctly})P(\text{All 0's send correctly})=p_1 ^{a 10^k} * p_0 ^{(1-a) 10^k}$$

Approach 2: For a particular bit
$P(correct) = P(\text{It is a 1})p_1 + P(\text{It is a 0})p_2=ap_1 + (1-a)p_2$
So, $$Pr = (ap_1 + (1-a)p_2)^{10^k}$$

I would be grateful for an explanation why one of these approaches is incorrect (or both, but I'm confident one of them is), as they both sound like they should work.

Comment: The two methods are addressing different questions.  In method $1$ we are assuming that exactly $a\%$ of the total were $1's$.  In method $2$ we are assuming that each digits is $1$ with probability $a$, independent of all other choices.  These are different questions.

Comment: Does every bit have to be correct in order for the message to be received correctly?  This isn't a fair assumption because such data is transmitted using error correction such as the Golay code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stress my earlier comment:  this is a problem of semantics, not math.

The problem, as stated, admits two interpretations.

Interpretation $I$:  The message contains exactly $a\times 10^k\,$  $1's$.
In that case, your first approach is correct.  Well, assuming that the noise hits each digit independently (but I think that's clearly the intent of the question).

Interpretation $II$:  Each digit independently has a probability $a$ of being a $1$.  In that case, the probability of getting a single digit right is $ap_1+(1-a)p_0$, just as you suggest in your method $2$.

I think either interpretation makes sense, so it's just a question of which one was intended. Your first method addresses the first interpretation, and the second method addresses the second.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Could you please add to your answer what could be added to the quoted question to make it unambiguous(for both interpretations)?

Comment: @janes  If I intended the first, I'd say explicitly that exactly $a\%$ of the message consisted of $1's$.  If I intended the second, I'd say that each digit was a $1$ with probability $a$, independent of all the other digits.